# Missing documented code objects when trying to create R package

Tags: r, r-s4, roxygen2

What do I need to add for avoid R CMD check complaining about missing doc ?

```
R CMD check --no-build-vignettes /Package_0.0.9.tar.gz
```

> checking for missing documentation entries ... WARNING Undocumented
> code objects:   ‘getPathwayStats’

Code looks like this, so getPathwayStats is documented .
Rd file is created by Roxygen so ...:/
Any idea would be more than welcome. Tks.

```
if (!isGeneric("getPathwayStats")) {
    if (is.function("getPathwayStats"))
        fun <- getPathwayStats
    else
        fun <- function(obj, ...) standardGeneric("getPathwayStats")
    setGeneric("getPathwayStats", fun)
}
#' Basic statistics
#'
#' @param obj    MYOBJECT
#' @param pval    P-value threshold.
#' @return A table with the pathways selected 
#'
#' @export
#' @examples
#' print('getPathwayStats')
#' 
#' @importFrom foreach %do% %dopar%
setMethod("getPathwayStats", "MYOBJECT", function(obj,
                                pval=NULL){ ...
  }
```

Comment: It looks like the closing curly brace is commented out where you define your function, is that the issue?

Comment: nope. Mistake from the copy paste. In fact all methods related to to S4 objects are said to be undoc . This one was just to give an example.